# I mixed the arguments of sgdisk -R /dev/sdY /dev/sdX

Tags: partition, raid1

I have two raid1 arrays and an LVM partition across both raid arrays.

A disk died and I tried to copy back the partition table of the other member to it using sgdisk -R

But I mixed the arguments, so after a reboot, the good disk seems as unusable as the bad one.

Can I fix it? I mean it was running well before I rebooted ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my issue.

Luckily my second raid1 array has a totally identical partition table, so I used sgdisk (the proper way this time) copying the partition table from a disk of that other raid1.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [testdisk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TestDisk) to recover your partition table. 
TestDisk is a free and open source data recovery utility it can:

- Recover deleted partition
- Rebuild partition table
- Rewrite the Master boot record (MBR)

Here a simple [howto](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step)

Comment: Testdisk did find the partitions but was telling me "The following partitions can't be recovered"